# Image to numpy-array: JPG vs. PNG

Tags: python, numpy, png, python-imaging-library, jpeg

My system: Mac OS X 10.7
Python 2.7.1
NumPy version 1.5.1

My code:

```
image = openImage(fileDir)  
print image  
image = np.asarray(image)  
print image
```

If I run this:

```
python main.py 1010.png
```

the output is:

```
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=10x10 at 0x10A835368>  
[[[226 226 226] ...    `
```

If I run this:

```
python main.py google.jpg
```

the output is:

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=488x640 at 0x10140B368>  
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=488x640 at 0x10140B368>
```

I cannot figure out why `numpy` can converts png's but can't do it on jpg's, why? How can I solve this?

**edit:**

ok tried with

```
image.show()
```

and got following error-message:

```
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

i solved the problem with the information i got from this page:
http://mariz.org/blog/2007/01/26/mac-os-x-decoder-jpeg-not-available/

Comment: Most likely you're missing the jpeg library, libjpeg, or so. I had a similar problem lately. I'm not sure how you install it on a Mac, but you have a starting point, at least.

Comment: i installed libjpeg and tried it again, but it didn't work ):

Comment: @8bui you should add your solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem with the information i got from this page:

http://mariz.org/blog/2007/01/26/mac-os-x-decoder-jpeg-not-available/